# Optimising a portfolio with weight constraints in Python

Tags: portfolio-optimization

I am looking to run weight portfolio simulations, but I would like to fix the weight of one asset and set lower/upper bound limits for the remaining assets.

I have only been using Python for a couple of months.

Below is the standard code I found to run simulated asset weights.  It works great; but I want to see how I could add weight constraints. Namely, fixing the weight of one asset and setting lower/upper bounds on the rest.

The data is uploaded via excel in the usual way.

Code below:

```
df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name='data1')

dRtns = df.pct_change()

number_of_portfolios=10000
number_of_assets=len(df.columns)

portfolio_returns = []
portfolio_risk = []
sharpe_ratio_port = []
portfolio_weights = []

for portfolio in range (number_of_portfolios):
    weights = np.random.random_sample(number_of_assets)
    weights=4*weights/np.sum(weights)   
    annualise_return=np.sum((dRtns.mean()*weights)*252)
    portfolio_returns.append(annualise_return)
    matrix_cov_port=(dRtns.cov())*252
    portfolio_variance=np.dot(weights.T,np.dot(matrix_cov_port,weights))
    portfolio_std=np.sqrt(portfolio_variance)
    portfolio_risk.append(portfolio_std)
    sharpe_ratio=((annualise_return)/portfolio_std)
    sharpe_ratio_port.append(sharpe_ratio)
    portfolio_weights.append(weights)
    
portfolio_risk=np.array(portfolio_risk)
portfolio_returns=np.array(portfolio_returns)
sharpe_ratio_port=np.array(sharpe_ratio_port)
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you,
H

Comment: Caution: the weights you are generating are not uniformly distributed (maybe the factor of 4 in the 11th line is an attempt to fix this?). Here is an example of a correct method to generate (unconstrained) random weights. https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/45897/random-portfolios-vs-efficient-frontier

Comment: Hi - in fact the 4 is not meant to be there.  I was playing around with the code.  i used:  weights=weights/np.sum(weights).  Thank you, H